# Mongoose only saves id and versionKey upon .save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not really sure what happens here, I set up my Schema properly, and the .save function itself works, however it only generates an object with id and versionkey (_id and __v) as properties.

Here's my code for the model (in the file todo.model.js):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Todo = new Schema({
    desc: String,
    progress: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', Todo);
```

And here's the function:

```
let Todo = require('./todo.model');
...
...
router.route('/add').post(function(req, res) {
    let todo = new Todo(req.body);
    todo.save()
        .then(todo => {
            res.status(200).json({'todo': 'todo added successfully'});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new todo failed');
        });
});
```

The routing etc. works, and a HTTP Post request with the correct json also returns "todo added successfully", but when i use get, i only get the id and versionKey of the object back.

```
{
"_id": "5ccd94f4a98874a847e54b00",
"__v": 0
}
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Please make sure `req.body` has any data.

Comment: @SaikatHajra thanks for the quick check. I guess I kinda skipped that logical step and immediately gave up, finding no reasons. The code wasn't wrong, I was missing the application/json header in my request

Comment: I suspected the same @just_deko