# Why won't .save() use the data I tell it too

Tags: javascript, mongoose, backend

Ok so this may be kind of odd, but hear me out.
  [first thing, this question is related to my issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55985630/mongoose-only-saves-id-and-versionkey-upon-save)

In a nutshell.  I am trying to make Mongo entries, everything is communicating, but my model.save() only save id and version.

The difference in what I am trying to do is that I don't want what to send any data.

I want to send a GET request, and I want the server to generate the initial data entry.  That entry just being a timestamp and a boolean.
So my code looks like this

```
  const CLOCK_IN = (req ,res ) => {

      const TimeCard = new TimeCardModel({
        startTime: new Date.now(),
        clockedIn: true
     })
     TimeCard.save()
       .then(res => {
         res.json(TimeCard.toJSON())
       })
        .catch(err => {
         res.json(err)
      })
    }
```

So what they say in the first question.  Is that the object is empty because the function can't read the data. So do I need to write up some code that will make the data I want before I call the entry saving function? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: The endpoint is generating an empty document instead of a document with predetermined properties.

Comment: Try just `Date.now()` instead of `new Date.now()` it might be causing a problem and looking like an empty document

Comment: `new Date.now()` will throw an error: `Date.now is not a constructor`.  Drop the `new` keyword.

Comment: nada, maybe a problem with my model?

Comment: Considering that we cannot see the code for the model, that is not a question we can currently answer.

Comment: It's my model...womp womp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My schema was wrong.

[The answer is in the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#models)

my model was defined

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({name: { Type: Date },
```

proper syntax is

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });
```